Настройка Prometheus
Создал web.yml файл по инструкции
basic_auth_users:
    admin: here_my_secret_pass

добавил в systemd:
...
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/prometheus \
   --config.file=/etc/prometheus/prometheus.yml \
   --web.config.file=/etc/prometheus/web.yml \
   --storage.tsdb.path=/var/lib/prometheus \
   --web.console.templates=/etc/prometheus/consoles \
   --web.console.libraries=/etc/prometheus/console_libraries \
   --web.listen-address=0.0.0.0:9091 \
   --web.external-url=
...

В итоге когда захожу по адресу:9091 выходит окно для авторизации. Логин и пароль из файла web.yml (прям через копирование и вставку) и мне говорит, что пароль неправильный.
Что не так?

«прям через копирование и вставку» — разумеется это не будет работать, потому что в файле web.yml пароль захэширован в bcrypt. А то, что вы попытались скопировать, намекает на то, что про это самое хэширование вы забыли

дак я же сам его туда написал через генератор. Сохранил в файл и оттуда вставил в web.yml и оттуда же копирую в форму

Не вижу в вашем комментарии ни одного намёка на bcrypt, что вызывает у меня подозрения, что вы про него принципиально не хотите вспоминать

В докумментации https://prometheus.io/docs/guides/basic-auth/ ничего не говорится про него - там тоже просто написано указать имя пользователя и пароль - я так и сделал

Ну хоть бы браузерным поиском по странице воспользовались: «First, generate a bcrypt hash of the password.»

И читаем документацию дальше: «supply the password when prompted» — password, а никакой не hash, то есть никаких копирований и вставок в окне авторизации делать разумеется не надо

действительно) спасибо
